# jquery ui resizable on click of buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to do the resizable control on click of button.

I have used the resizable plugin in jquery ui to resize the image.

But now i need to do image increase or descrese size using plus and minus buttons.

Do anyone know how to do it??

Comment: Code snippet or jsFiddle please ...!

Comment: without seeing any of your code - you will probably need to set up the buttons so that they increase or decrease the size when clicked, you will most likely end up using the `.width()` and `.height()` jquery functions to get and set the image values. here is the example for width...http://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: a fiddle would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use jQuery UI for this.  That provides a standard set of features for the end-user to interact with.  If you want to mess with the height and width of a div, do something directly like this...

```
<div id="less" class="button">-</div>
<div id="more" class="button">+</div>
<div class="box"></div>    

$("#more").click(function() {
    var h = $('.box').height();
    h = h + 20;
    $('.box').css({height: h, width: h});
});

$("#less").click(function() {
    var h = $('.box').height();
    h = h - 20;
    $('.box').css({height: h, width: h});
});
```

Working fiddle here... http://jsfiddle.net/TUwV2/